# Configure vsdiffmerge for multiple files at once

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, git-diff

I am using git 1.9.4 for windows from (http://git-scm.com/download/win).

`$ git difftool branchA branchB`
Opens up `vsdiffmerge` one file at a time for all the files in the diff.

`$ git difftool --no-prompt branchA branchB` attempts to open up all the files at once (what I want to happen) but vsdiffmerge can't handle this properly with any of the bellow happening.

- multiple empty instances of vsdiffmerge will open
- an already open instance will have its open tab replaced with the next file in the diff list

How do I configure my difftool so the behavior is one instance of vsdiffmerge, with multiple tabs of all the diffs?

gitconfig:

```
[diff "astextplain"]
    textconv = astextplain
[rebase]
    autosquash = true

[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\IDE\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
    keepbackup = false
    trustexistcode = true
[merge]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\IDE\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" //m
    keepbackup = false
    trustexistcode = true
```

Comment: Dying to know how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, to remove the `/t` (or `//t`, because of the escaping) at the end.

The argument `/t` opens a temporary tab. This is the tab, that is replaced. Without this argument Visual Studio opens a permanent tab and adds it to the other tabs that are already open.

*See also here:* 
https://roadtoalm.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/

PS: Even though I removed the `/t` at the end, for me the diff was still opened in a temporary tab. The reason for this - at least in my case – was, that Visual Studio or Git ignored all settings in tool `vsdiffmerge`. After I renamed the tool everything worked as expected.

So, I suggest renaming the tool to something like `vsdiff`, remove the `/t` and try it again.

Don’t forget to call it like `git difftool -t vsdiff --no-prompt branchA branchB` to explicitly use the tool named `vsdiff` or to set `vsdiff` as default tool.

Comment: I forgot about the empty instances. As far as I can tell, Visual Studio opens an empty Instance, whenever git tries to diff a file that don't exist on both sides - like if a file was added or deleted.